# Current group in class level bean validation

Tags: java, bean-validation, spring-validator

I have some group validations in a bean:

```
@FichaValida(groups={Ficha.DatosGenerales.class, Ficha.Economia.class})
public class Ficha {
    public interface DatosGenerales{}
    public interface Documentos{}
    public interface Ubigeo{}
    public interface Economia{}
    @NotEmpty(groups = {DatosGenerales.class})
    String apPrimer;

    @NotEmpty(groups = {DatosGenerales.class})
    String apSegundo;

    @NotEmpty(groups = {DatosGenerales.class})
    String preNombres;

    @NotEmpty(groups = {Documentos.class})
    String tiDocumento;

    @NotEmpty(groups = {Documentos.class})
    String nuDocumento;


    @NotEmpty(groups = {Ubigeo.class})
    String deDepartamento;

    @NotEmpty(groups = {Ubigeo.class})
    String deProvincia;

    @NotEmpty(groups = {Ubigeo.class})
    String deDistrito;


    @NotEmpty(groups = {Economia.class})
    String nuIngreso;

    @NotEmpty(groups = {Economia.class})
    String nuGasto;
    //members, setters and getters
}
```

And these methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "datos-generales.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String datosGenerales(
        @Validated({Ficha.DatosGenerales.class}) Ficha ficha,
        BindingResult bindingResult){
}

@RequestMapping(value = "documentos.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String documentos(
        @Validated({Ficha.Documentos.class}) Ficha ficha,
        BindingResult bindingResult){
}

@RequestMapping(value = "economia.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String economia(
        @Validated({Ficha.Economia.class}) Ficha ficha,
        BindingResult bindingResult){

}
```

How I can know in the validator class which group is currently validating?

```
public class FichaValidator implements ConstraintValidator<FichaValida, Ficha> {

    private FichaValida fichaValida;

    public void initialize(FichaValida fichaValida) {
        this.fichaValida = fichaValida;
    }

    public boolean isValid(Ficha ficha, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        /*
        if(Ficha.DatosGenerales.class==...){
            //some validations
        }else if(Ficha.Economia.class==...){
            //some validations
        }
        */
        return true;
    }

}
```

I need to do validations with the members according the current group validation, by example if DatosGenerales group is validating, only use members related to it.

Comment: What group do you want? The group specified on the constraint which is getting validated (that you can get indeed via `initialize`) or the group which is currently requested/validated by the `Validator.validate` call? In case of the latter, it is not possible. The concept of constraint validators and groups are orthogonal. What is your use case? Do you want to write a class level constraint. Your code seems to be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public boolean isValid(Ficha ficha, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if(Ficha.DatosGenerales.class==this.fichaValida.value()){
            //some validations
        }else if(Ficha.Economia.class==this.fichaValida.value()){
            //some validations
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: this.fichaValida (member of FichaValidator) is initialized once, it has the same value in each validation, then the answer don't work.